# Trying to reach home network devices/airport extreme files outside my home network by connecting with Openvpn to a Pivpn server at home

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi, airport-extreme

What I'm trying to do is to reach my home network router's (airport extreme) disk outside my home network. Using the airport extreme like a NAS to reach the files I have on it.

I have successfully setup a VPN server on my Raspberry Pi that I have at home using PiVPN. I'm using OpenVPN on my Laptop to connect to the VPN server. When I am connected to the VPN on my laptop with some other network (tried using shared connection from my iPhone) it shows the same public ip that my home network has so that works.

So what I am trying to do now is to reach the files I have on my airport extreme, I can reach these files from any device connected to my home network by connecting to the Public ip of the router (airport extreme) or by a .ddns that I have set up.

The problem that I need help with is that when I am connected with the VPN outside my home network, I am not able to connect to this address. Is there a quick fix for this or am I missing something?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use the NAS IP, not the router IP. If you are VPNed to the inside of your network, you can connect directly to the NAS using the NAS's LAN IP address.

Comment: The file storage or "NAS" is built in to the router (airport extreme) so they are the same device and have the same ip